# How to add a control to a Form programmatically?

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0

I'm trying to add a control(Label) inside of a panel. 
Please see the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AddControlProgramatically
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label lbl = new Label();

            for (int x = 0; x <= 3; x++)
            {
                //create new label location after each loop
                //by multiplying the new value of variable x by 5, so the new label 
                //control will not overlap each other.
                lbl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(52 + (x * 5), 58 + (x * 5));
                //create new id and text of the label
                lbl.Name = "label_" + x.ToString();
                lbl.Text = "Label " + x.ToString();

                this.panel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Here's the form. What I'm trying to accomplish is to programatically generate 3 diffent control labels. But as you can see, It only displays the last one. Please help me regarding this. I know there's something wrong in my code (cause it's not working).Thanks...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to accept answers..just a newbie in this forum. How exactly to do that?

Comment: When you ask a question there is a check mark below the up/down vote. To accept a correct answer click on the check mark. It gives the user additional points as well as let others know which answer works if they have a similar problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the `Label lbl = new Label();` inside the loop.

And make the offset bigger, change this...

```
 lbl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(52 + (x * 5), 58 + (x * 5))
```

...to:

```
lbl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(52 + (x * 30), 58 + (x * 30))
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a new label in each loop iteration. Right now you are only creating one label.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int x = 0; x <= 3; x++)
    {
        Label lbl = new Label();

        //create new label location after each loop
        //by multiplying the new value of variable x by 5, so the new label 
        //control will not overlap each other.
        lbl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(52 + (x * 5), 58 + (x * 5));
        //create new id and text of the label
        lbl.Name = "label_" + x.ToString();
        lbl.Text = "Label " + x.ToString();

        this.panel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, looking at the code it looks like 4 labels should be created. (`x <= 3`).

Comment: I wish I'm good as you in programming. I only started programming last year because of my friend. I'm not an IT person, but i find it very fun and interesting. Now I'm doing self study, and I choose C# language to study. My friend also lend me books about programming. (I think I want to shift my course)... : )

Comment: Sir it's already working... its just the spacing that makes the other labels not to appear, they overlapped each other.... I really appreciate your responses. Thanks again.

Comment: @yonan2236 Looking back the spacing does seem like it wasn't enough, sorry I missed that! Hang in there it gets easier the more familiar you get with a programming language!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `Label lbl = new Label();` inside your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question, but apparently nobody took the time to get it right....
You keep overwriting the same Label object instance. Instead create a list of Label instances and then add them to your form like this:

```
        List < Label > myLabels = new List<Label>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Label lbl = new Label();                
            //create new id and text of the label
            lbl.Name = "label_" + i.ToString();
            lbl.Text = "Label " + i.ToString();
            lbl.Width = 50;
            lbl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(52 + (i * lbl.Width), 50);
            myLabels.Add(lbl);
        }
        foreach (Label l in myLabels)
        {
            this.Controls.Add(l);
        }
```